# Adding Codec to Add Content-Length in my Requests in WebClient

Tags: java, netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty, spring-webclient

I want to add some sort of `ChannelOutboundHandler` to my `WebClient` that takes the request, add the '`Content-Length`' header to it, and forwards it. I know that the class `HttpContentEncoder` does this. How do I configure this class in my `WebClient`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add `Content-Length`, you do not need any handler.
You can do it like this:

```
String requestBody = "something";
String response =
        WebClient.create()
                .post()
                .uri("https://postman-echo.com/post")
                .contentLength(9)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(requestBody))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
System.out.println(response);
```